# How to change the opacity of a container when the button is clicked?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a button to change opacity of a container when button:focus but it doesn't seem to work.

here is a example of button:

```
  <button type="button" class="bpi" id="bpi1">1519</button>
```

here is an example of container:

```
<div class="infospi" id="ipi1"> lorem ipsum </div>
```

here is the css that's not working:

```
    .infospi{
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  background: #ff63b5;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  top:150px;
  color:white;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-align: justify;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

#bpi1:focus #ipi1{
  opacity: 0.8;
  }
```

Comment: To build a CSS selector, we need to see the structure of the button and the container in context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saying `#bpi1` is a parent of `#ipi1`. You want a [sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors). So

`#bpi1:focus + #ipi1`

Answer (score 1):

Your css uses a [decendant selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp). It needs to be a child element.

**Descendant Selector**

The descendant selector matches all elements that are descendants of a specified element.

```css
.infospi {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ff63b5;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-align: justify;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

#bpi1:focus #ipi1 {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="bpi" id="bpi1">1519 
 <div class="infospi" id="ipi1"> lorem ipsum</div>
</button>
```

Comment: It needs to be a descendant, not necessarily a child.

Comment: This is invalid HTML. A `<div>` is not allowed as a child of `<button>`. It is unclear, in the question, if that is what he is doing.

Comment: @Rob Although this works it is, invalid html. A sibling selector, as in your answer, if a better solution if the two elements are in fact siblings.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where these elements exist determines if you could only use CSS versus JS. For example, if the elements were close in proximity you could use CSS.

1519
  lorem ipsum

```css
.bpi:focus + .infospi {
  opacity:.6;
}

  .infospi{
  width:400px;
  height:300px;
  background: #ff63b5;
  border-radius: 3px;
 /*  position: absolute;
  top:150px; */
  color:white;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-align: justify;
  /* opacity: 0; */
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="bpi" id="bpi1">1519</button>
<div class="infospi" id="ipi1"> lorem ipsum</div>
```

Comment: I just noticed you changed the structure of your question. Since the button is now inside the div my example is slightly irrelevant. The concept is still good if you were to move the button. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with [:focus-within](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus-within/) pseudo-element:

```
.infospi:focus-within {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

But, keep in mind [this is not supported by all browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-focus-within).

Actually, safest way to achieve this would be to do it with some simple Javascript, something like this:

```
$('.infospi .bpi').focus(function() {
    $this().parent().addClass('focused-child');
})

$('.infospi .bpi').blur(function() {
    $this().parent().removeClass('focused-child');
});
```